# Python 2.7.3 BeautifulSoup- Remove u2019 and u2122 from string

Tags: python

I would like to modify the following piece of code to also replace u2019 and u2122 with a blank space, in addition to the comma it is already replacing with a blank space.  How should I proceed?  Thanks!

```
if(link != None):
    items.put([link.text,link['href']])
    f.write((link.text).encode("utf-8").replace(',','')+","+link['href'].encode("utf-8").split('&')[0]+newlinechar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `replace` multiple times like so:

```
f.write((link.text).encode("utf-8").replace(',','').replace(u"\u2019", '').replace(u"\u2122", '')+","+link['href'].encode("utf-8").split('&')[0]+newlinechar)
```

This is **inefficient** however because a new String need to be recreated many times (Strings in Python are immutable). So consider using a regex instead to match and replace all 3 in one sweep.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u"xdu\u2019sfs,"
>>> print s
xdu’sfs,
>>> print re.sub(u'[,\u2019\u2122]', '', s)
xdusfs
```